# SQL Server Express installation fails

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

I'm having a problem installing either Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express or 2008 R2 Express.

The installation starts and I choose "New installation...", I get to the step where I choose what should be installed, and it continues to the step where I specify the instance name, but when I click next in the step, I get an error popup saying:

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following:

Could not find the file.

Error code 0x84BB0001
```

Then it says the install crashed...

I used to have 2008 R2 Express installed prevously but had to reinstall it.

Now my guess was that there are files left somewhere, so I ran Windows Installer Cleanup Utility to remove anything related to SQL Server, but it still dosnt work.

What can I do to fix this? We're really looking for a solution for this.

Edit, copied from log just before the stack:

```
2012-09-20 12:07:00 SQLBrowser: CalculateUserNamePassword: SQL Server Browser service exists: retrieving current service account.
2012-09-20 12:07:00 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get start account for service SQLBrowser
2012-09-20 12:07:00 Slp: Invoking QueryServiceConfig Win32 API for buffer size
2012-09-20 12:07:00 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.WaypointAction" threw an exception during execution.
2012-09-20 12:07:00 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: Thread was being aborted. ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have previously had an SQL Server installation.  The installation correctly uninstalled, but left behind your *databases*.  Unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) and SQL Server 2012 does not support installation over that data, which is especially obvious if the previous installation was a newer version than the present one in which case there is no way to downgrade the database schema versions.

Find your .mdf/.ldf files on the disk and remove the whole data folder.