# Error when installing Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, database, service, failed-installation

I've never had any instance of **Microsoft SQL Server** before, when installing the Database Engine Services I receive this error: `0x84BB0001`.

Error details:

> Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
>   Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I've no idea what to do, please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried searching for this error code before? There are two other questions with answers [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509809/sql-server-express-installation-fails) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021321/error-0x84bb0001-while-installing-sql-server-2012). You should also add more details ony what you've done before.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. Both questions are about installing a newer version and they receive this error code due to bad removing of previous installs, right?

Is it possible to upload the log file of the installation?

Comment: Here's some extra details, I can also upload a log file but I've been checking it myself and it's not really helpfull..

Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.

Feature failure reason:
An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.

Error details:
§ Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
Error code: 0x84BB0001